# Error while installing Dashing gem in Rails (Mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install Dashing gem, but I have the following in showing in the terminal. I am following a [tutorial from DevCasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukoItMznDiY):

```
EtienneLo: user1$ rails g dashing:install
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby25, which recognizes
warning: 2.5.1-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.5.0.
warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
We are preparing the algo
Could not find generator 'dashing:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'merit:install' or 'bootstrap:install'
```

I have the gem install and already run `bundle install` command

Comment: try with `bundle exec rails g dashing:install`

Comment: @fanta, i just tried and got the same error message .

Comment: when you do `gem list` do you see it listed in the output ?

Comment: Yes, i see `dashing (1.3.2)`

Comment: Can you replace `gem 'dashing-rails'` with `gem 'dashing-rails', git:'https://github.com/gottfrois/dashing-rails.git'`

Comment: Hi, it works fine now, thank you! I had the following `Resolving dependencies...................
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    redis (= 4.0.1)

  In Gemfile:
    redis

    dashing-rails was resolved to 2.6.2, which depends on
      redis (~> 3.2)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.` but I removed `redis` and install the dashboard. All good now. thank you!

Comment: Not sure my method worked actually I have the following : `   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
{ 70162412804580 rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:
  70162412804580   job:
  70162412804580     Rufus::Scheduler::EveryJob "2s" {}
  70162412804580   error:
  70162412804580     70162412804580
  70162412804580     Redis::CannotConnectError`